# How to .getData() from CKEditor server side (.NET)?

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, xss

In APS.NET, CKeditor *.Text* server side property does not return the same then *.getData()* client side method.

Example:
If i wrote 
`<script>` on WYSIWYG editor, server side *.Text* property returns `<p><script></p>` and clientSide *.getData()* returns `<p>&lt;script&gt;</p>`

I couldn't find any server side property that returns what *.getData* does. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To get the same values as on the client use `String value = Server.HtmlEncode(ckeditor.text)`.

But this will also encode `<p>` and `</p>` tags.
If you dont want it the replace all `<p>` and `</p>` with some char encode it and replace chars with `<p>` and `</p>` tags.